# nginx reverse proxy to apache webdav

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, webdav

So I started using nginx to reverse proxy to a couple of services a have home. One of them is my webdav server under Apache. Here is my config file:

```
server {

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name webdav.server.com www.webdav.server.com;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://192.168.1.200/backup;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

    location /backup {
            proxy_pass http://192.168.1.200/backup;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

If I remove the `location /backup { ... }` directive, it stops working.
Is there a neater way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, actually the problem was solved editing the Apache Webdav config file.

From:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory "/var/www/html">
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /backup /mnt/Backup/Windows
    <Directory /mnt/Backup/Windows>
       DAV On
       AuthType Basic
       AuthName "Windows"
       AuthUserFile /xxxx/passwd.dav
       Require valid-user
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

To:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

   ServerName webdav.eddienetworks.ddnsfree.com
   ServerAlias *.webdav.eddienetworks.ddnsfree.com
   DocumentRoot /mnt/Backup/Windows

   <Directory /mnt/Backup/Windows>
      DAV On
      AuthType Basic
      AuthName "Windows"
      AuthUserFile /xxxx/passwd.dav
      Require valid-user
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

The resulting nginx proxy file became:

```
server {

   listen 80;
   listen [::]:80;
   server_name webdav.server.com www.webdav.server.com;

   location / {
      proxy_pass http://192.168.1.200/backup;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
   }
}
```

Hope that can help some in the future.